# Templated multistack implementation - how?

Tags: c++, containers, std

I need a 'MultiStack' taking different types of objects, putting each type in a separate stack.

This is what it looks like so far. The open problem is: how to handle the containers for a number of different T

```
class MultiStack
{

public:

    template<typename T>
    const T& Get()
    {
        return Container<T>.back();
    }

    template<typename T>
    void Push( const T& t )
    {
        Container<T>.push_back( t );
    }

    template<typename T>
    void Pop( const T& /*t*/ )
    {
        Container<T>.pop_back();
    }

private:

    // this does not make sense, we obv. need one stack for each T
    // template<typename T>
    // std::vector<T>           Container;

};
```

Now, I could use the old trick, putting the Container in a member function, like

```
template<typename T>
auto GetContainer()
{
    static std::vector<T> C;
    return C;
}
```

but I don't like this anymore in the age of multi-threading. It is 'dangerous', right!?

Is there a better, elegant way? It is conceivable that I know the allowed types beforehand, if that helps realizing it.

Comment: check this gist : https://gist.github.com/ravikiran0606/209a2d58eeb5da9c077161814487098f
is it helpful?

Comment: @DivyanshSingh Not at all. Have I mentioned that I'm looking for an 'elegant' solution? I already have code for 3 specific types, but I need to add more, so this question arises.

Comment: First of all `GetContainer` returns a copy, so wouldn't do anything useful for you. But even if it would return a reference or pointer to it then the `static std::vector<T> C` would shared between different instances of `MultiStack`.

Comment: Do you mean 'last of all' or 'least of all'? Obviously enough, the intention was &, but thanks for the coaching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I don't like this anymore in the age of multi-threading. It is 'dangerous', right!?

Issue is not multi-threading. initialization would be fine.
You still have to protect/synchronize access though, as regular multi-threading code.

Issue is that the container is not per instance of `MultiTask`, as it is static.
It is mostly as if `MultiTask` were a Singleton.

> It is conceivable that I know the allowed types beforehand, if that helps realizing it.

That helps, you can then use `std::tuple`, something like (C++14):

```
template <typename ... Ts>
class MultiStack
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    const T& Get() const
    {
        return GetContainer<T>().back();
    }

    template<typename T>
    void Push(const T& t)
    {
        GetContainer<T>().push_back(t);
    }

    template <typename T>
    void Pop()
    {
        GetContainer<T>().pop_back();
    }

private:
    template <typename T>
    const std::vector<T>& GetContainer() const { return std::get<std::vector<T>>(Containers); }
    template <typename T>
    std::vector<T>& GetContainer() { return std::get<std::vector<T>>(Containers); }

private:
    std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...> Containers;
};
```

Comment: Looks good. What happens if called with unsupported T, though?

Comment: Makes sense. Have to handle that myself.

Comment: You might add something like `static_assert((std::is_same_v<T, Ts> || ...))`

Comment: Tupelitios. The nifty `std::get<T>` saves the day.